# JSON.NET unknown type deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json

Assume I have following json strings, where some property name differes ("dataA", "dataB"), but it contains the same structure

```
{
  "mainprop": "val",
  "dataA": { "prop1":"val", "prop2":"val"}
}
```

and

```
{
  "mainprop": "val",
  "dataB": { "prop1":"val", "prop2":"val"}
}
```

How I can deserialize these jsons to objects with following generic class

```
Class Generic
{
  string mainprop;
  DataClass data; 
}

Class DataClass
{
  string prop1;
  string prop2;
}
```

In another words, how I can handle deserialization based on name of the property.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Comment: You could use regular expressions to pre-process the json strings to match your target classes.

Comment: I want to avoid string preprocessing and try to find more elegant solution

Comment: In general json.net parse json string and able to fire MissingMember error, so if will be option to handle this with getting member name and ability to return custom deserialization for my "data" member

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a generic deserialization (to `Dictionary<string, object>`) and then map the values yourself, but I suspect this isn't what you're looking for.

The only way I can think off the top of my head is to make two dummy objects for deserialization / serialization purposes only.

```
public class GenericA : Generic {
    public DataClass dataA { get { return data; } set { data = value; } }
}

public class GenericB : Generic {
    public DataClass dataB { get { return data; } set { data = value; } }
}

Generic a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericA>("JSON using dataA");
Generic b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericB>("JSON using dataB");
```

I haven't tested this code.

## Edit

You may want to attribute your `data` property with `[JsonIgnore]` so you can serialize `GenericA` and `GenericB` without having the same property twice.

Comment: Thanks for response, But your solution require to generate dummy classes. In my case the array of "names" for properties is too large and dynamic. Is any way to programmatically handle some missingmembers? JSON.NET Settings have MissingMemberHandling attribute, but I can't see how to handle it and somehow return proper class deserialization